# Log Spring transaction rollback finish

Tags: spring, logging, transactions, mybatis, spring-transactions

I am tuning DB performance of our Spring 3.1.1 + MyBatis 3.1.1 application.

We use both: `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` and `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager`

I would like to see how long it takes to rollback/commit some transactions. I have added to my log configuration

```
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="D" />
</logger>
```

However I see only when rollback starts

```
2015-02-19 09:49:36,183 DEBUG [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 
'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] 
TransactionTemplate: Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
```

Is there any way to see when the rollback actually finishes?

Comment: Are you using annotations for transactions?

Comment: Not. We use Apache Camel and it uses policy based logic to add all BD operations to transactions